# Custom HTML Button wrapped in Link not working

Tags: reactjs, button, react-router, next.js

I have made a custom `Button` component that returns HTML `button`. Now I am using this `Button` inside `Link` from `next-routes`. The problem is that it does not work this way. Weird thing is that button works correctly if I use HTML `button` inside `Link`. However, both button are being rendered in the DOM in exact same way. Following is the code:

```js
// Button.js

import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

const Button = ({
    children,
    newClass = "",
    onClickHandler = () => { },
    isSubmitting = false,
    inlineBtn = true,
    disabled,
    primary,
    secondary,
    basic,
    notCentered = true,
    shaded,
    miniLoader,
    type = "button",
    isTransparent,
    fontClass = "",
    small
}) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button
                className={classNames(
                    `${isTransparent ? 'btn-transparent' : 'btn'} ${fontClass} ${newClass}`,
                    {
                        "btn-block": !inlineBtn,
                        "col-mx-auto": !notCentered,
                        "btn-primary": primary,
                        "btn-secondary": secondary,
                        "btn-basic": basic,
                        shaded: shaded,
                        loading: isSubmitting,
                        "loading-sm": miniLoader,
                        "btn-sm": small
                    }
                )}
                disabled={disabled}
                type={type}
                onClick={onClickHandler}
            >
                <span>{children}</span>
            </button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export { Button };
```

The following does not work:

```
<Link route="/register/location">
  <Button basic small>
    Sign Up
  </Button>
</Link>
```

The following works fine:

```
<Link route="/register/location">
  <button className="btn btn-basic btn-sm" type="button" onClick={() => { }}>
    <span>Sign Up</span>
  </button>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your `Button` component as the following.

```
const Button = ({
  as = "button",
  children,
  newClass = "",
  onClickHandler = () => {},
  isSubmitting = false,
  inlineBtn = true,
  disabled,
  primary,
  secondary,
  basic,
  notCentered = true,
  shaded,
  miniLoader,
  type = "button",
  isTransparent,
  fontClass = "",
  small,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const Wrapper = as;
  return (
    <Wrapper
      className={classNames(
        `${isTransparent ? "btn-transparent" : "btn"} ${fontClass} ${newClass}`,
        {
          "btn-block": !inlineBtn,
          "col-mx-auto": !notCentered,
          "btn-primary": primary,
          "btn-secondary": secondary,
          "btn-basic": basic,
          shaded: shaded,
          loading: isSubmitting,
          "loading-sm": miniLoader,
          "btn-sm": small
        }
      )}
      disabled={disabled}
      type={type}
      onClick={onClickHandler}
      {...rest}
    >
      <span>{children}</span>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

This will allow custom `Wrapper` to be used for your `Button` component. And we pass every inherited props into your `Wrapper` so that your `route` props will be received in your `Link` component.

You can then use it like so

```
<Button basic small as={Link} route="/register/location">
  Sign Up
</Button>
```

This uses the ES6 spread operator syntax. Basically you render your `Button` component `as` a `Link` component, and any inherited props will be passed to the `Link` component, hence `route` props is passed into `Link` component.

This follow the API Design Approach similar to Material-ui's [spead](https://material-ui.com/guides/api/#spread) approach. This will allow your component to be more flexible as well.

Comment: I am using this Button in other places where it does not acts as a link and executes onClick(). In those cases, the wrapper is not needed and should not be passed. It means I would have to make a special Button for the cases requiring button to act as a link. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Yes you can use your component as it is because the default value of `as` props is `button`. It is just an enhancement that allows your `Button` component to be more flexible

Comment: Oh okay. But using this component would require to give `a` tag to pass a child and give the classes to the anchor. It would be difficult to maintain, I suggest. However I am accepting your solution because it serves the specific purpose correctly apart from that it would not work for me. Thank you very much bro.

Comment: Glad that helped ! This pattern is used in quite a number of popular UI frameworks. Using this pattern can give more flexibility to your components. The `as` props is based on [Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/augmentation#as-prop), as for [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#component-prop), they uses `component` props instead. They does the same thing, just the props name is different. The example that I wrote for you is a simple one, you can potentially make your `Button` component more flexible.